# Picking one element from each of the two sets

Tags: algorithm

We have a bunch of people, say `P1`, `P2`, `P3`, `P4`. We have two set. Say one set is `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and the other set is `{A, B, C}`. Each person has a list of elements he can choose from each of the two sets. When a person has both elements from the two sets, we say this person is ready. We want to maximized the number of ready people. The same element cannot be used twice. Like the following example:

```
People: P1, P2, P3, P4
Set1: {1, 2, 3, 4}
Set2: {A, B, C}

P1 can pick from {1, 2} and {B, C}
P2 can pick from {1, 2, 3} and {C}
P3 can pick from {1, 2} and {B, C}
P4 can pick from {1} and {A, B, C}
```

One possible solution for the above example would be:

`P1 picks none
P2 picks 3 and C
P3 picks 2 and B
P4 picks 1 and A`

Thought of using greedy for each set separately, but in fact to get the optimal solution, the solution for one set sometimes has to compromise for the other set.

Edit:
Max flow solution solves the original problem. Now what if each person has his own preference when choosing from `{1, 2, 3, 4}`? For example, `P1` prefers `2` over `1`. When `P1` has a choice to pick either `1` or `2`, he will always pick `2`.

Comment: Can you use integer programming?  This seems like it could lend itself quite well to a formulation of that type.  Constraints would be that each element can only be used once and each person can only pick one element from each set.  Optimize the number of people who have picked two items

Comment: This problem is closely related to three-dimensional matching. You may want to look into solvers for that problem.

Comment: I rolled back the last edit to remove the picture and make the question cleaner for readers who may find it through search engines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved by computing the maximum flow on a flow network constructed as follows:

- Construct a source node `Source`
- Construct one node for elements of the first set `#1` through `#4`; connect each node to the `Source`.
- Construct one node for each person. Connect each person to noodes `#1`..`#4` based on their compatibility lists (i.e. `P1` gets connected to `#1` and `#2`, `P2` to `#1`, `#2` and `#3`, and so on)
- Construct one node for each element of the second set `A`..`C`. Connect each node to person nodes according to their compatibility lists.
- Construct a node `Drain`, and connect each node from `A`..`C` to the drain.

All edges and all vertices have capacity of 1. Here is an illustration based on your compatibility lists:

[image: MinCat / Max flow graph]

Now run one of [several max flow algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Solutions) on the flow network defined by this graph. The max flow that you obtain provides an optimal assignment:

[image: Flow diagram with flows]

Comment: I've seen an identical problem in a course on algorithms I took (except we were matching light bulbs to electrical switches). I thought that was the most elegant solution in the entire course.

As an aside, you can use the graph to enforce constraints. For example, suppose you  can't select object `A` if you've already selected `1` or `2`. When constructing the graph, simply do not add edges between `A` and either `1`or `2` (the layers in the above diagram will have to be reordered, but that does not change the solution)

Comment: Sorry, I have a picture showing a counter-example to upload to this comment. But looks like comment cannot contain picture? The picture is here http://i60.tinypic.com/2vmc7zp.png

Now P3 have two edges (one from #1 and the other from #2), which is not allowed. But the flow here is 3.

Comment: @HardyLi Please see the edit. It is not necessary to post an edit to a question in addition to posting a comment, because the comment is specific to a single answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for reminding me. I've added my picture to my original post. I think you're right! Once vertex capacity is set to 1, problem solved!